# Javascript - Enter Switch case based on return value of a function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
switch (buttonValue) {
  case '8':
    // ...
    return
  case specialCase(buttonValue):
    // having trouble getting here
}

const specialCase = (buttonValue) => buttonValue > '4' && buttonValue !== '8'
```

How do I enter the `specialCase` block within the switch statement? If `buttonValue = 7` for example, the `specialCase()` function returns `true`, but I don't ever enter that case block.

I have a need to abstract the logic into the separate `specialCase()` function since some of the conditions I'm checking are complex. Basically, I'm trying to *avoid a case statement that looks like*:

```
case buttonValue > '4' && buttonValue !== '8' && buttonValue < '19' && .... etc
```

Am I just formatting the case syntax incorrectly or are you not able to use a function's return value to enter the case?

Comment: Did you try to use the `default` statement followed by a `if`? Something like `default: if (specialCase(buttonValue)) ...`

Comment: Because "true" does not equal "buttonValue", using conditions in switch is bad practice.

Comment: don't think you can use such a syntax

Comment: There are many more cases. The `specialCase` is not the final case

Comment: Then use if statements.... Maybe you should show more code and we can give you better suggestions on updating the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with expression in `case`. Just move your function before the `switch`.

Also, as someone mentioned in the comments - switch is not a `true` / `false` thing. In order for the `case` to be matched, you need to return the case value in your function, not just `true`.

Comment: Yes there is a problem with it.

Comment: I am not the OP and there is a problem with it, I mentioned it in the comments.

Comment: Thanks @RoboRobok , your updated response makes it clear. I will instead return the case value instead of a boolean. I'll accept this as the accepted response once it allows me to. Cheers

Comment: @bruh No, don't do that. Write an `if`/`else` statement instead.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi . I understand this is not the desired solution. However, this solution helped me to understand "why" it wasn't working and provides an, although not ideal implementation - a working one. I will move forward with an `if/else` but this is still an acceptable answer